# Среда для разработки визуальных приложений C++

Tags: ide, c++

Не так давно появилась необходимость в создании визуальных приложениях на сях, сначала одного, потом другого... делфями раньше обходился, но теперь от паскаля чего-то подташнивает(

Может, я слишком привередливый, но MS VC++ показались жутким бредом. Есть ли что лучше и, если не сложно, распишите, у какой среды какие преимущества. Пока что остановил внимание на Builder C++, но что есть ещё?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [IDE для C и C++][1].

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/3592/ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-c-%D0%B8-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте Qt, имеет открытый исходный код и для некоммерческий целей бесплатен. Можно связать со студией, а можно ковыряться и в их ide.

Answer (score 0):

Сам недавно только начал, но у Visual Studio 2010 множество положительных качеств для всех этапов программирования